# Make left menu fixed inside parent container

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to make left menu sticky, but when i give it position:fixed then the right container which is also inside parent div comes down in the left side. Please help. Thanks... This is my html structure:

```
<div class="midwrapper_inner">
    <ul>
        <li class="leftbox">
            <div class="left_div content">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="middlewhitebox">
            <div class="right_div_content">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `float` css proparty

Comment: use a second div to hold the space, or use margin, fixed position is like absolute in that it removes the element from the document flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="midwrapper_inner">
<ul>
    <li class="leftbox">
        <div class="left_div content">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="middlewhitebox" style="margin-left: XXXpx" >
        <div class="right_div_content">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

where xxx is the width of leftbox.

To be honest though I would remove the `ul` completely and use divs

```
<div style="height: 1000px;">
    <div style="width: 200px; height:200px; position: fixed; background: red;" ></div>
    <div style="margin-left: 200px; width: 200px; height:200px; background: green;" ></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wyxop52k/

Answer (score 0):

> Css

```
.leftbox{position:relative; float:left; margin-right:15px; }
Try This ...(Y)
```